# Intercepting Outbound message from WCF before serialisation

Tags: c#, wcf, protobuf-net

I have implemented Proto-buf.net over WCF and my WCF services are now using this as their serialiser, all good so far.

However, I need to add some information from the message into the HTTP headers so that these packets can be tracked around the network.

I have implemented a Message Inspector that allows me to add Header information, however at this point the message has already been ran through the proto-buf serialiser and is no longer readable.

Is it possible to intercept the message before serialisation and still have access to the HttpRequestMessage Headers? If not can I put some information  about the request somewhere that will be accessible from the message inspector?

Many thanks

Comment: maybe this can help, not 100% sure http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/26/wcf-extensibility-iparameterinspector.aspx

Comment: Cheers Yaron, The blog got me moving forward in the right direction, I have added the answer below if anyone else is interested in doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yarons comment got me moving in the right direction

A ParameterInspector pulls out the value and places it onto the operationContext using a cusom operationContext extension

```
    public class TestParameterInspector : IParameterInspector
{
    public object BeforeCall(string operationName, object[] inputs)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void AfterCall(string operationName, object[] outputs, object returnValue, object correlationState)
    {
        OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Add(new ContextSessionExtension() {SomeData = "testme"} );
    }
}

    public class ContextSessionExtension : IExtension<OperationContext>
{
    public void Attach(OperationContext owner)
    {

    }

    public void Detach(OperationContext owner)
    {

    }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }

}
```

The value is then pulled out and placed into the HTTP headers using a MessageInspector

```
    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {

        return null;
    }

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var test = OperationContext.Current.Extensions.Find<ContextSessionExtension>().SomeData;
        object httpRequestMessageObject;
        HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestMessage;
        if (reply.Properties.TryGetValue(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, out httpRequestMessageObject))
        {
            httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessageObject as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(httpRequestMessage.Headers["MYTEST"]))
            {
                httpRequestMessage.Headers["MYTEST"] = test;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("MYTEST", test);
            reply.Properties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you use the TestParameterInspector ?